# Comparison between ROR & PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, comparison

I started working with PHP around 2 years ago and now I am thinking to switch technology to have better experience. I read on different blogs about the comparison, some of them are abusing PHP and some are protecting PHP to get abused.

> 1- My question here is that what is your opinion about this?
>
> 2- Which one is the better (Regardless, learning ROR is way harder than
> learning PHP)?
>
> 3- Which one is most popular and being worked on these days?

Looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: choose ruby if you like that, do not choose just only because you think it is more popular and its easy to make money with that

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a framework and php is a scripting language. It is 2 different thing.

This blogpost may give you some idea on how PHP's going in the future .
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/01/php-6-pissing-in-the-wind

1- My question here is that what is your opinion about this?

I like ruby because it treat everything as an object. 
For example

```
"length".length #=> will return length of the string
```

in php you use a function to do that which is less intuitive

```
strlen("length");
```

2- Which one is the better (Regardless, learning ROR is way harder than learning PHP)?

It depends on you and what you need.

e.g
Most rails hosting cost you more than php hosting. so PHP is better in this case.

3- Which one is most popular and being worked on these days?

a quick google search will give you this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_programming_language_popularity

Answer (score 0):

I would say stick with PHP if you want web programming, you have more job's opportunity it's easy to find a hosting that supports PHP, the community is bigger. For me that is more than enough to stick with it.

I wouldn't go to explain difference between boths because i don't have enough experience with ROR to do so. But PHP is getting better and better.

You can give  this post a read for some more information about the "evolution" of php! http://fabien.potencier.org/article/64/php-is-much-better-than-you-think .

ps: sorry for the biased post :)